# Why is "onclick" only working once and fails to update?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why this onclick button is only working once.
Basically I am testing to see if the "heart" or "wishlist" button is clicked on. When clicked, console.log the name of the product so I can confirm it. But it only picks up the first product. When I click the wishlist button on the second product.
It gives this error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at products:1:10)"`
When I go to that line it just show ''

I have also tried using a

```
const wishlistBtn = document.querySelector('.wishlistBtn');
wishlistBtn.addEventListener('click', (product_name) => { console.log(product_name) })
```

But it just returns that the property is null. I'm wondering if the reason is because of the innerHTML I am including all of this in.

**Javascript:**

```
const getProducts = () => {
    return fetch('/get-products', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
        body: JSON.stringify({})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        createProductCards(data);
    })
}
var wishlist = (product_name) => {
    console.log(product_name);
}


const createProductCards = (data) => {
    let parent = document.querySelector('.container');
    let start = '<div class="product-container">';
    let middle = '';
    let end = '</div>';

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].id != decodeURI(location.pathname.split('/').pop()) && !data[i].draft){
            middle += `
            <div class="product-card">
                <div class="product-image">
                    ${data[i].discount === '0' ? ``:`
                        <span class="discount-tag">${data[i].discount}% off</span>
                    `}
                    <img src="${data[i].images[0]}" class="product-thumb" alt="">
                    <button class="card-btn wishlistBtn" onclick="wishlist('${data[i].name}')"><i class="bi-heart"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h6 class="product-brand"><a href="/products/${data[i].id}">${data[i].name}</a></h6>

                    ${data[i].discount === '0' ? `<span class="price">$${data[i].totalPrice}</span>`:`
                        <span class="price">$${data[i].totalPrice}</span>
                        <span class="actual-price">$${data[i].actualPrice}</span>
                    `}
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
        }
    }
    parent.innerHTML = start + middle + end;
}

getProducts();
```

Comment: The thing you've named `product_name` in the `click` handler is actually the click event object (and so should be named something like `event`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found my problem. The issue was with one of my products having quotations inside of it for some reason but once removed the onclick worked multiple times while sending the product name to a function to keep track.

The problem with the answers given was also that I didnt want to display the name at all inside the button itself `<button class=“test”>Item</button>` instead this is what I needed `<button onclick=‘func(${passname})></button>` so that would have not worked when attempted but it gave me a general idea for future references. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector` works only on the first matched element. You may need to use `document.querySelectorAll` & attach event after the for loop has completely finished it's execution

```
const wishlistBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlistBtn').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', getProductName)
})

function getProductName(product_name) {

  console.log(product_name)
})
```

Here is an example

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', getButtonValue)

})

function getButtonValue(elem) {
  console.log(elem.target.innerHTML)

}
```

```html
<button class="test">1</button>
<button class="test">2</button>
<button class="test">3</button>
<button class="test">4</button>
<button class="test">5</button>
<button class="test">6</button>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a nodelist, I don't think it has `forEach`... you might need to borrow from an array like [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.wishlistBtn'), (item) =>...

Comment: You can use `forEach` on node list. Check out the code snippet atached

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` only returns the first instance of the selector. So the first wish list button on your page is the only one that gets a listener attached.

If you're coming from JQuery, this is a nuanced difference. To add the event listener to every `.wishlistBtn` you could do something like:

```
const wishlistBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlistBtn');
[...wishlistBtns].forEach(wishListButton => wishListButton.addEventListener('click', (product_name) => { console.log(product_name) })
```

There are two differences:

1. The use of `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList of all of the elements that match the `.wishlistBtn` selector.
2. Iterate over the NodeList and add an event listener to each individual node. Unfortunately NodeList isn't exactly an array so `[...wishlistButtons]` is a quick and dirty way to convert it to an array using the relatively new spread operator `...`